# Can you help identify these plants in my new garden?

Tags: identification

I have just moved to Berkshire in the UK and this is the first house I have had with a garden. I've been trying google search to try and identify these plants, but I'm not having any luck so I hope this forum can help me.

No1 is a plant with large leaves (bigger than my hand), with serrated edges. It stands about 1m tall.

[image: IMG]

The stems are green but some of them appear to have spots on. There are also little red (buds?) where the leaf is attached to the stem.
Close up of the leaves.

[image: IMG]

No. 2 is a tall plant with green leaves turning yellow/orange. It is over 6ft.

[image: IMG]

No 3 Is a climber. It has small green leaves and small white round buds/berries.

[image: IMG]

No.4 I think is a Rhododendon?

[image: IMG]

No 5 Is a tall shrub with dark green leaves and is already over 6ft - seems to have the potential for a large spread too.
[image: IMG]

This is the first time i have posted to the forum so i hope the images work ok. If they don't here is a link to the album with all the plant photos. http://s996.photobucket.com/user/Caidan_Trubel/library/Garden%20plants

Thanks!

Comment: While I think you will get a collection of answers. But this is not a good style for this site: I suggest you make a question per plant. Which some descriptions you can give or observations you made. This could help others in the future.

Comment: Re-reading my comment now makes me realize how bad my grammar and writing is, can't edit it anymore ... sorry.

Comment: Hi Caidan, welcome to the site. As others have noted, a multipart question like this doesn't fit the Q&A format of this site. It would be better split up into multiple questions, one per plant.

Comment: Can't answer cos its put on hold, but the top one is Hydrangea paniculata, 2nd one I'll have to get back to you, I know what it is, but infuriatingly it's not coming to mind, 4 is a rhodo, 5 is bay (Laurus nobilis) and No. 3 does resemble some kind of Euonymus, as Kevinsky says. Eureka, Philadelphus coronarius for No. 2, but check for white fragrant flowers next year.

Comment: After looking again, I'm not sure the first one is Hydrangrea - it could be Weigela florida. If its the latter, it should get very large and produce pink/deep pink bell shaped tubular flowers. I'd like to know what time of year this photo was taken... leaf size bit too small for hydrangea, but if it was early in the year, its possible.

Comment: Thanks very much for everyone's input. I should have separated out the plant pictures - sorry about that. Caidan

Comment: @Bamboo No. 1 looks remarkably like a hydrangea that I have in my yard. Not sure of the species. caidan I'll watch for your posts and will have a picture handy to compare the leaves.

Answer (score 1):

Number 3 [Euonymus fortunei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euonymus_fortunei) or one of it's hundreds of cultivars. If I'm right the flowers will match the Wikipedia description of

> "The flowers are inconspicuous, 5 mm in diameter, with four small
>   greenish-yellow petals. The fruit is a four-lobed pale green pod-like
>   berry, which splits open to reveal the fleshy-coated orange seeds, one
>   seed in each lobe"

Sometimes described as a jewel among evergreens it is also considered an [invasive species](http://www.invadingspecies.com/invaders/plants-terrestrial/winged-euonymus/) in parts of North America. It originates in East Asia. Often attacked by scale it is a vigorous sprawling climber whose main attraction is the glossy leaves.

Number 4 A rhododendron, with the hundreds of cultivars it's difficult to identify it further